# Mapbox RMUserTrackingModeFollow not on map center

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, mapbox

I am trying to use RMUserTrackingModeFollow with MapBox in an ios app. Although it seems to be working fine (following the gps location) the map is not centered on user location but it moves so the location dot sticks to middle right for portrait mode and bottom center in landscape.

Working on Xcode 6 with minimum targeting for iOS 7.1 with auto layout and size classes on and a storyboard, based project.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

I have found that I was having a wrong approach. I had unchecked the "Resize View from NIB" although this was causing the above behavior. I now checked this and added

```
self.mapView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

Now everything resized finely and the map is centered.